# An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository :: Android SDK installation from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, package, android-sdk-manager

Continuously facing problem in Android SDK installation from Android Studio. Working behind a proxy. Proxy set up well. Disabled all network firewalls. Tried running Android studio as Administrator. But failed.

Please suggest an appropriate solution.

Following are related logs:

```
Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.




java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.

com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.WizardException: java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.

    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.promptToRetry(InstallOperation.java:114)
```

Comment: Can you try running Android Studio  as administrator ?.

Comment: It seems like this could be any issue from your connection to your security settings... 

Comment: @sunilsunny yes I have tried. but same result.

Comment: @RandallArms, not getting your point, could you please bring out any solution?

Comment: I think you need to set a Proxy for Android Studio.

Comment: @sunilsunny proxy set up is there... that is why is starting download ..... but after 50-60% it fails

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Looks like bad network.

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: Me too!! Same issue..